# Order of Arguments in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameters, segmentation-fault

So, I'm working with some C code. I've defined the following function:

```
int load_csv(size_t L, size_t W, CSV_DATA csv_data[L][W], char file[])
```

If i call this function, everything works as it should.

If, however, I change the order of the first two arguments, so that the function is defined as follows:

```
int load_csv(size_t W, size_t L, CSV_DATA csv_data[L][W], char file[])
```

I get a segfault when I try to save data to csv_data. Can anyone give any insight into the reasoning why the arguments defined before a struct parameter (csv_data in this case) has to be in the same order?

edit: as requested, here is the entire function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    enum { is_int, is_float, is_char } type;
    int ival;
    char cval[10];
    float fval;
}CSV_DATA;

int load_csv(size_t L, size_t W, CSV_DATA csv_data[L][W], char file[])
{ 

   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;

   int i = 0;

   FILE *fstream = fopen("iris.csv","r");

   if(fstream == NULL)
   {   
      printf("\n file opening failed ");
      return -1 ;
   }   

   while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL)
   {   
    int j = 0;

     record = strtok(line,",");
     printf("%s", record);
     while(record != NULL)
     {   

        csv_data[i][j].type = is_char;
        for (int k=0; k < strlen(record); k++){ 
          csv_data[i][j].cval[k] = record[k];//record;          
        }   

        j++;

     record = strtok(NULL,",");
     //printf("%s", record);

     }   
     ++i;
   }   
  return 0;
}
```

edit: here's the calling code. Eventhough..I'm not using L or W anywhere in the called function...

```
int main(){

        int L = 500;
        int W = 50; 
        CSV_DATA csv_data[500][50];
        char file[10] = "iris.csv";
        load_csv(L ,W , csv_data, file);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Because C compiler doesn't recognize function parameters by name.

Comment: `5 - 4 != 4 - 5`, the order of arguments matters for some functions.

Comment: no, that's not what i'm saying. I'm saying that when, I change the way the function is defined in the signature, i get a segfault.

Comment: @Silveris Can you say more about this? I wasn't aware that the compiler doesn't recognize parameters by name!

Comment: @lurker I'm saying that swapping arguments in the signature causes this.

Comment: Um.. You swapped the *parameters*. But did you swap the arguments at the point of the call? If you did not modify the calls, they *obviosly* it will crash. You are passing a, say, `[10][2]` array but telling the function that it is actually a `[2][10]` array. No wonder it crashes on out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Killingsworth: when you rearrange the order of arguments in the signature, you also have to rearrange the paramaters at every place where the function is called accordingly.

Comment: @Killingsworth or show at least how you call `load_csv` in both cases.

Comment: @xing this is clearly not the problem if you look at the code.

Comment: @Killingsworth Must contradict - exactly this (xing) *is* the problem. A little more explicit: With `load_csv(3, 9, ...)` called in the first case (assumed being correct there), you pass a [3][9] array. If you swap the parameters, but nothing else, you still pass a [3][9] array - but L, which was previously assigned 3 now gets assigned 9 and W, previously 9, now 3. So you passs a 3x9 array, but tell the function it is a 9x3 array...

Comment: @Killingsworth: Would **you** please consider we did read the question, a<nd that's the reason for DV and most likely CV?

Comment: So, is it the case that the values passed to L and W in the function must match the size of the passed in 2d array for the third parameter? This is likely the point of my confusion.

Comment: Still not enough information. And I'm not in the mood to ask your for every missing information. Read [ask] and follow the advice! And use your debugger.

Comment: @Olaf How is this still not enough information? I've provided everything except the struct definition.

Comment: @Olaf I'm familiar with the community guidelines. I've provided all of the salient code. Now, literally all of my code is in the question. No one has given me the answer to my question: why does this code not work when the first two parameters IN THE SIGNATURE are switched EVENTHOUGH I'm not using those parameters AT ALL in the function.

Comment: @Killingsworth: 1) You did not. 2) YOu **have been** given the answer. The problem is, you seem to lack the basics to understand it. These are explained in every good C book. Askers are assumed to understand the basics of a language well enough to comprehend the answer (and that's why you also don't get what's missing). This is not meant as offence, but to make you get a good C book and work through the chapters. We are not a tutoring service. Online "tutorials" and youtube videos are **not** a viable way to learn C. Nor is trial& error.

Comment: @Killingsworth OK, another try: If you pass an array of any type to a function, you only get passed the address of, which decays the array to a pointer within the function. This is why you won't get the size of the array back within the function using sizeof, but only the size of a pointer (8 on typical modern 64 bit hardware). However, type pointed to and thus the size is well-known, this is why `++n` advances by 1 byte for a char array, but four bytes for an int array (provided sizeof(int) is 4).

Comment: @Aconcagua I appreciate the help. Can you say if it the case that the values passed to L and W in the function must match the size of the passed in 2d array for the third parameter?

Comment: If you pass a two-dimenstional array, you get a pointer to a specific type. This specific type is - guess: an one-dimensional array of length of the second dimension. Example: passing int[3][7] to a function passes a pointer to an array of which all the elements themselves are arrays of length 7 (i. e. int (*data) [7]; be aware that this is totally different from int* data[7], which is (int*)data[7]). `sizeof(data)` will be 8 (pointer size), but `sizeof(*data)` is `7*sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Killingsworth The outer dimension of the array gets lost, just as the dimension of a ordinary one-dimensional array gets lost, because of arrays being passed to functions are passed as pointers. The inner dimension, however defines the data type of the elements in the array, and thus the size. So the W parameter must match, the other on not (at least, if not used for range checking). Similar for a 3d array: The two inner-most dimenstions must match, the outer one not (but should, as normally provided for range checking).

Comment: @Killingsworth: Judging from the attitude you show with such comments and you ignoring well-meant hints clearly says you already know everything and don't need the basics. Interestingly, It is not me asking.

Comment: @Olaf Yours are the only comments I'll be ignoring going forward. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Killingsworth If it helps for understanding: These are two absolutely equivalent definitions for your function:
`int load_csv(size_t L, size_t W, CSV_DATA csv_data[][W], char file[])`
`int load_csv(size_t L, size_t W, CSV_DATA (*csv_data)[W], char* file)`
As you see, L is not used in the definition, but W is! Now imagine, file was not null-terminated - how would you tell the function the length? Guess, an additional parameter... This is what L is the equivalent to.

Comment: @Aconcagua I think I see what you're saying. Thanks so much for all of the help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap the order of the parameters in the function definition, then you need to also swap them either in the array parameter declaration or in the function *call*.  IOW, if you change

```
int load_csv(size_t L, size_t W, CSV_DATA csv_data[L][W], char file[])
```

to

```
int load_csv(size_t W, size_t L, CSV_DATA csv_data[L][W], char file[])
```

then you *either* need to change the declaration of `csv_data` as well:

```
int load_csv(size_t W, size_t L, CSV_DATA csv_data[W][L], char file[])
```

*or* you need to change the parameter order in the function *call*:

```
load_csv(L, W, csv_data, file);
```

to

```
load_csv(W, L, csv_data, file);
```

Otherwise, the dimensions of `csv_data` in `load_csv` will be reversed from the dimensions of `csv_data` in `main`, leading to out-of-range array accesses at some point.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. Thanks so much for reading the question fully and giving a thoughtful answer!

Answer (score 1):

The order shouldn't matter - its more likely what you are doing with the values inside the function that has changed - did you change the order of the values where the function is called?

Comment: I don't understand why that should matter, because I'm referencing the variables by name.

Comment: _because I'm referencing the variables by name_: not sure what you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: name does not matter, load_csv(10,5) is different to load_csv(5,10)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm still not sure how this is causing a segfault. If I'm not using W or L inside the function and I'm only using them to declare variables to be used in csv_data, I don't see how changing the order of the parameters would cause a segfault. Does assigning values to W and L implicitly add values to csv_data? Is this what i'm missing?

Comment: @Killingsworth we don't know either, there is not enough information in the question so it can be answered. Please provide a [mcve] <-- click here and read.

Comment: @Killingsworth There is some fundamental misunderstanding how parameters work! Parameters are referenced by name -- **within** the function! But when you call a function, the arguments are assigned to the names in the order you pass them! I. e. calling `load_csv(3, 9, ...)` will assign 3 to the first parameter, no matter if called L or W, and 9 to the second one, again independent from the name. So if you swap teh parameters, you get the assignment vice versa. And if you do not swap the arguments in the function call...

Comment: @Aconcagua If you look at the code, I'm not using L or W ANYWHERE withing the calling function. Is it the case that the C compiler tries to reconcile the L and W variables passed in to a function with the actual size of the passed in array?

Comment: @Killingsworth Oh, yes, you do!!! However, indirectly: `csv_data[L][W]` tells the function the dimensions of the array. `csv_data[i][j]` is actually compiled to something like `*((CSV_DATA*)csv_data + i*L + j)`. Can you imagine how fatal this can get if you swap dimensions???

Comment: So, when I call the function, I cant do something like this:

        int L = 0;
        int W = 0; 
        CSV_DATA csv_data[500][50];
        char file[10] = "iris.csv";
        load_csv(L ,W , csv_data, file);

...eventhough I'm not using L or W inside the funtion?

Comment: No, you can't. Via L and W, you provide the dimensions of the array of your third parameter (side note: in my comment above, it must be i * **W**, of course...). A two dimensional array is actually only syntactic sugar, it is simply some contiguous memory. A 2x3 twodimensional array is not different from a ordinary one-dimenstional array of length 6, only the access calculation (see my previous comment) is taken away from you...

Comment: To be very precise: If you look at the calculations (i * W + j), the value of L truely is not used... So instead of swapping the parameters, you could have passed any arbitrary value to L without provoking any failure... Actually, passing `data[L][W]` passes the address of data to the function, such that the function in reality receives a pointer `int(*data)[W]` and thus L is just as irrelevant as if you passed "hello" to a function `void f(char[77]);`. You *could* have used it for range checking, though...